# json-simple How to get value from index?

Tags: java, json, parsing, json-simple

I want to get a value from json based on index. The code bellow is working but I get the value from a String reference.

```
String s="{\"GA087SH85IZETRI-123872\":\"0\",\"GA087SH85IZETRI-123873\":\"-1\",\"GA087SH85IZETRI-123874\":\"0\",\"GA087SH85IZETRI-123875\":\"-1\",\"GA087SH85IZETRI-123876\":\"0\",\"GA087SH85IZETRI-123877\":\"0\",\"GA087SH85IZETRI-123878\":\"0\",\"GA087SH85IZETRI-123879\":\"0\",\"GA087SH85IZETRI-123880\":\"0\",\"GA087SH85IZETRI-123881\":\"0\"}";
JSONParser parser2 = new JSONParser();
Object objs = parser2.parse(s);
JSONObject jsonObject2 = (JSONObject) objs;
System.out.println(jsonObject2.get("GA087SH85IZETRI-123873"));
```

I'm lookin for a way to do something like:

```
System.out.println(jsonObject2.get(0));
```

Comment: which json library are you using?

Comment: i guess he is using json-simple: https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/

Comment: Yes... I'm using code.google.com/p/json-simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In json-simple, JSONObject extends HashMap:

http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/

It's unfortunately not possible to get value by index cause the HashMap is unordered.